# Astronvim: how to install neotest-jest?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

Maybe somebody knows how to add [neotes-jest](https://github.com/nvim-neotest/neotest-jest) to [neotest](https://github.com/nvim-neotest/neotest) configuration
inside [AstroNvim](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim)?

P.S. Documentation didn't help